# How to bind XML data file in CodedUI? Example Program please?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, datasource, coded-ui-tests, data-driven

This is my Data Source

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|Data Directory|\\Input.xml", "testcase", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

When I execute this, I get the below error

> The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read
>   the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see
>   "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
>   Error details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The XML File is located in the project's folder location. How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Check the steps given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469100/how-to-run-a-test-many-times-with-data-read-from-csv-file-data-driving/25742114#25742114 . There is not much difference between how XML and CSV files are added and used in Coded UI tests.

Comment: Does the DataSource really say `, "|Data Directory|\Input.xml", `? I believe that `\I` is not a valid character in a string and it should provoke a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of above code use this

```
[DeploymentItem("Project_Name\\Input.xml"), DeploymentItem("Input.xml"), TestMethod,
 DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\Input.xml", "datarow", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

use below code to get TestContext:

```
 public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

use below xml with named as LoginInfo.xml and In LoginInfo.xml(Right click on LoginInfo.xml---->Properties) properties set Copy Always in copy to output Directory.

```
<xml>
  <authentication>
    <username>Biren</username>
    <password>BirenPassword</password>
  </authentication>
  <authentication>
    <username>Viren</username>
    <password>VirenPassword</password>
  </authentication>
  <authentication>
    <username>Bond</username>
    <password>BondPassword</password>
  </authentication>  
</xml>
```

## use below code in Class to check it

```
 [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\LoginInfo.xml", "authentication", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("LoginInfo.xml"), TestMethod]

public void RunningXML()
{   string username=TestContext.DataRow["username"].ToString();
    string password = TestContext.DataRow["password"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("userName  :" + username);
    Console.WriteLine("passWord  :" + password);
}
```