# How to perform datadriven approach using coded ui VSTS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csv, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

In Visual Studio 2010, I have created data driven using VSTS coded UI automation. But I am not able follow the same steps in 2013.

I got some useful info in MSDN, but that too is not sufficient still I am facing issues while adding a .csv file.

Datadriven is quite easy in 2010, but in 2013 it is entirely different I added a .csv file through
 Project -> Add New Item....but it is not working

Also, in 2010 while adding a file a code will generate automatically. The same code is not appearing in 2013. PFB the code from 2010

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\TestDatas.csv", "TestDatas#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("TestDatas.csv"), TestMethod]

Comment: Please answer to this question ASAP.....It is pushing my client's delivery date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a test many times with data read from .csv file (data driving)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469100/how-to-run-a-test-many-times-with-data-read-from-csv-file-data-driving)