# How to I inject programmatic text into my Coded UI test (as opposed to recorded text) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

The recorder works fine for quickly getting some steps thrown down, but I need to be able to store and set arbitrary text. Let's say I generated a new admin user called Admin001. I want to be able to set the text for the control to be "Admin001", not whatever was recorded when I first used the builder.

I know you can do data bindings to CSV and the like, but that's too burdensome. I want to be able to write C# code to change which text is typed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code attempt:

```
            var loginElement = new UILoginInternetExploreWindow().UILoginDocument.UIUserNameorEmailAddreEdit.Text;
```

So I'm able to get the property .Text (I think), but not actually set it...

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469100/how-to-run-a-test-many-times-with-data-read-from-csv-file-data-driving/25742114#25742114 , concentrate on the part after "**Read the CSV fields and use them in the test**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to set the property just do:

```
new UILoginInternetExploreWindow().UILoginDocument.UIUserNameorEmailAddreEdit.Text = 
"Some Text";
```

or:

```
var loginControl = new UILoginInternetExploreWindow().UILoginDocument.UIUserNameorEmailAddreEdit;
loginControl.Text = "Some Text";
```

Comment: Okay, that works. Not sure why it wasn't working for me yesterday.