# How Can I Make a Test Method on Coded UI Data Driven If that Data file doesn't exist at run time since data source doesn't exist yet

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I know that for me to create a data driven test that i need to use a datasource with the test method, and that the datasource had to have already existed.

My question is how about if you want to make a test method data driven but you don't have the datasource file at run time.  
**Edit**
What i mean is I want to basically iterate over the same test X number of times.  The reason I dont have the data is because i have to first fetch the data first and then iterate over it.

below i created a test that ran for each of my hyperlink but after the test pass i only get results **Passed Once** instead for each iteration of my hyperlink.  I also tried to launch something in the "[TestInitialize()]" section and assign my data file to it but since the data file has to be constant(or already exist), i cant do it.  Any help with this would be great

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Verify_Rates_Links()
    {
         HomePage getLinks = new HomePage(GlobalVariable.Browser);
         int PicCount = 0;
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        PageObjects.Shared.SharedBetweenPage StarTest = new PageObjects.Shared.SharedBetweenPage(GlobalVariable.Browser);
        getLinks.GetAllHeaderLinks("Rates", "3", GlobalVariable.Rates_Links);           
        foreach ( HtmlHyperlink links in GlobalVariable.Rates_Links)
        {
        Assert.IsTrue(
            StarTest.LetsGoToHomePage()
            .LetsclickLink(links)
            .VerifyLocationPage("Rates","Rates", "Rates", "VerifyRateslinkBreadcrumb" + PicCount.ToString() + ".jpg", "VerifyRatesHeader" + PicCount.ToString() + ".jpg"),
            "There is an issue with Rates to create new membership APP one or more of the work flows is not work");
        //Playback.Cleanup();
            //testcl
        PicCount++;
        }



    }
```

~Will

Comment: If the data source is not available at runtime then how do you plan to get the data to datadrive the test? Please [edit] the question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469100/how-to-run-a-test-many-times-with-data-read-from-csv-file-data-driving

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve. What does *"have to first fetch the data"* mean and where is any of that shown in the code. I think this question may be too broad according to [help/on-topic].

Comment: Use [a Test Case in TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx) if you need to do it at run time.